# API for stackoverflow data

Tags: python, stackexchange-api, stackexchange

is there any API through which I can access StackOverflow data in python?

I am also trying to fetch data from Bigquery but I am getting a **403 error**

> Forbidden: 403 GET
>   https://dp.kaggle.net/bigquery/v2/projects/stackoverflow/datasets/posts_questions:
>   Forbidden: [stackoverflow.posts_questions]

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
data_ref = client.dataset('posts_questions', project='stackoverflow')
que_data = client.get_dataset(data_ref)
```

Comment: You have two questions, not one. As to your first, you may want to look at https://api.stackexchange.com/docs for small requests, or the [archive.org data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) for bulk.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package in pypi called StackAPI

```
pip install StackAPI
```

A quick google will give you the results

Comment: in this problem I am trying to fetch data from BigQuery